# How to check the age of a person if it is less than 18 show an alert on Microsoft Dynamics 365 (Model driven app)?

Tags: function, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I am new to MS Dynamics 365 (Power App) and want to create a function where it checks if the age is less than 18 or not and displays an alert if the person is less than 18.

I have developed a model driven app using solution and table (entity) and want to know if the person is less than 18, when the person enters the age in the text column.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Search for "javascript event onchange in dynamincs crm" in google pls

Answer (score 1):

You can use a business rule for this. I am assuming that when you say "text column" is really an integer value and you are referring it as text.

So you have a column named "Age" of type "Whole number"

[image: Column properties]

Now, you can create a business rule (Define if you need this only or the form or the entity)

[image: Add Business rule]

On the condition box, configure something like this and click "Apply" at the bottom of the window
[image: Business rule condition]

From the "Components" tab select "Show Error Message" and add the configuration
[image: Error Message less than 18]

Select the scope for the Business rule and save it. After it saves you have to activate it so it starts working.

[image: Activate business rule]

Now, when the user enters the age and it is less than 18, you'll get the error message and this will prevent the record from saving until valid data is entered.

[image: Age error message]

If you are using a text or date type for the age, or you just want an alert without validating the data onSave, then you'll have to add some JavaScript code, **please note that this is just an example and you should follow best practices for resource naming, validations and JavaScript encapsulation**.

```
function validateAge(exContext) {
    if ( !exContext )
        return;

    let formContext = exContext.getFormContext();

    if ( formContext.getAttribute("new_age").getValue() < 18 )
    {
        alert("Less than 18");
    }
}
```

Open the form where you want the validation and add or create the library for your JavaScript
[image: Add JavaScript library]

If you are creating the web resource

[image: Create Web resource]

Select the field that will trigger the validation, select the "Events" tab and click on "+ Event Handler"
[image: Add event handler]

Configure the event handler, save and publish

[image: Configure event handler]

[image: JavaScript less than 18]